# How to automate UIDatePicker to select a past date using KIF framework

Tags: ios, uidatepicker, kif

I have a date picker with these 4 columns  "Thu Jul 23, 10, 20, AM”.
I want to automate date picker  using KIF to select  a past date like Wed Jul 15,10,20,AM. I could select Jul 15  but with unknown year resulting in wrong weekday.It supposed to be "Wed Jul 15" but resulting "Mon Jul 15". I want to select a particular past date in the  current year(2015).This is my current working code.Any help is greatly appreciated.

NSArray *pastDate = @[@"Jul 15", @"", @"",@"”];
[tester selectDatePickerValue:pastDate];

Comment: I am not having idea of KIF framework, But instead of having array of strings, try having array of NSDate. NSDate *date1 = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:(7*60*60)]; NSArray *pastDate = @[date1]

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I did some work around to select past and future dates in the date picker using KIF framework. Instead of setting date picker value to past/future date ,I am trying to scroll the date picker to past/future date.Here is the code snippet

```
- (void)testSelectPastDate{
    [tester scrollViewWithAccessibilityIdentifier:@"datePicker" byFractionOfSizeHorizontal:0.1 vertical:0.3];
}

- (void)testSelectFutureDate{
    [tester scrollViewWithAccessibilityIdentifier:@"datePicker" byFractionOfSizeHorizontal:0.2 vertical:-0.2];
}
```

you can adjust the vertical factor based on your requirement